# In Hammer, how can I make a sound come from a physics object?

Tags: hammer

In hammer, I want to make a functioning radio, as in the sound comes from the radio itself and when you pick it up and move it around the sound's origin moves with the object.

Comment: I have tried making the parent of an ambient_generic to the prop, but ambient_generics don't have the parameter for a parent

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out,

Comment: If you found a solution post an answer to your own question to let future users know how you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Basically, you want to go into the ambient generic, and set the source entity to whatever you want the sound to come from. make sure to name the entity.